# Problemas con reportes Rdlc con Parametros - C# VS 2017 espacio de nombres de destino no valido

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc, vs2017

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Estoy haciendo un sistema que tiene varios requerimientos de informes y comprobantes. Para generarlos utilizo un report wiever al que dinámicamente le mando el informe RCLD y los conjuntos de datos en formato DataView, y en algunos casos parámetros.

En un primer momento comenze a trabajar los reportes en el VS 2013 realizando un montón de ellos sin problemas.

Luego migre al VS 2017, donde instale la version 15 de report viewer. Ademas borre las referencias viejas y puse las nuevas a version 10. Cuando ejecuto y tiro los Rdlc generados anteriormente en vs 2013 se ejecutan normal incluso aquellos que tienen parámetros.

El problema arranca después al generar un nuevo informe ya en el vs2017 y enviarlo al report viewer.

En un primer momento al hacer el rdlc nuevo no genera errores, pude agregar los conjuntos de datos sin errores y ejecutarlo sin problemas. (Sin parametros) en vs 2017.

Al generarse así, sin parámetros, si voy y lo abro al rdcl en un editor xml se ve que en la etiqueta report xmlns el schema indicado es
***http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition***
Con eso el rdlc anda bien.

Pero luego, al momento de agregar un parámetro y ejecutar la llamada al report viewer para visualizar el rdcl me tira el error

***"la definición del informe no es valida. La definición del informe no es válida. Detalles: la definición de informe tiene un espacio de nombre de destino no válido 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefination' que no se puede actualizar".***

Efectivamente abro el rdcl en el editor xml y veo que **al agregar el parámetro el espacio de nombre de destino se cambia de 2008/01 (con el que funciona sin problemas el rdlc) a 2016/01, el cual genera el error**. El primero funciona, el otro no.

Lo probé muchas veces pero es siempre es el mismo error, la verdad me esta volviendo loco. Intente desinstalar report viewer pero se me colgó la maquina y al volver ya no me abrió más el VS jaja. Lo estoy re instalando en este momento.

Espero se entienda la descripción del problema. Realmente requiero un salvavidas. Saludos y desde ya gracias